# Проблема с вызовом функции, название которой переданно через параметр

Tags: python, ооп, rest

Мой вопрос заключается в том, что у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы при вызове программы в методе
`InputBox` через системные аргументы загружались функции класса `YandexDiskOperations`

Так как это можно реализовать?

```
import sys
import yadisk
import os
import pyAesCrypt
from os import stat, remove
import random


class YandexDiskOperations():
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_auth()
        print('n4')

    def get_auth(self):
        self.y = yadisk.YaDisk("94885fad3a5e407b8cda5af348597aae", "59d96c74713947b9bad0f691dffb5699")
        url = self.y.get_code_url()
        with open("data.txt", "rb") as token_txt:
            code = token_txt
            try:
                response = self.y.get_token(code)
                print('n1')
            except yadisk.exceptions.BadRequestError:
                print('n2')
                sys.exit(1)
        self.y.token = response.access_token
        print('n3')

        if self.y.check_token():
            print("Токен получен")
        else:
            print("Срок жизни токена истек, либо введён не правильно")

    def move(self, from_path, to_path):
        try:
            operation = self.y.move(from_path, to_path)
            while True:
                status = self.y.get_operation_status(operation.href)
                if status == "in-progress":
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print("Still waiting...")
                elif status == "success":
                    print("Success")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Не выполнено, ошибка: {0}".format(status))
                    break
        except:
            print('Ошибка в выполнении')


    def listdir(self, path, **kwargs):
        try:
            operation = self.y.listdir(path)
            print(operation)
        except:
            print('Не выполнено, ошибка')

    def is_dir(self, path, **kwargs):
        try:
            operation = self.y.is_dir(path)
            print(operation)
        except:
            print('Не выполнено, ошибка')

    def is_file(self, path, **kwargs):
        try:
            operation = self.y.is_file(path)
            print(operation)
        except:
            print('Не выпонено, ошибка')
class InputBox():
    def __init__(self):
        YandexDiskOperations.self.locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('''
    Это приложение работает через код подтверждения.
    Для начала работы перейдите по ссылке:
    https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=94885fad3a5e407b8cda5af348597aae
    После - создайте папку token.txt и вствьте его туда
    ''')

    start = YandexDiskOperations()
    location = InputBox()
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так:

```
class YandexDiskOperations:
    ...
    def additional_func(self):
        locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

class InputBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.smth = YandexDiskOperations()

    def another_func(self):
        self.smth.additional_func()
```

Comment: Да, параметры с командной строки теперь действительно принимаются, но тут есть одно но:
///self.smth.locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
///AttributeError: 'YandexDiskOperations' object has no attribute 'locals'

Comment: попітайтесь засунуть `self.locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])` в отдельную функцию (например additional_func) в`YandexDiskOperations()` и потом: `class InputBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.smth = YandexDiskOperations()

    def another_func(self): 
        self.smth.additional_func()`

Comment: Всё-равно та же ошибка: AttributeError: 'YandexDiskOperations' object has no attribute 'locals'

Comment: впишите  `locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])` в `additional_func()` , без `self`. Иначе его трактует как атрибут класса, которого действительно нет.

Comment: Да, проблема решена, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле то решение не является верным, потому, что объекты внутри классов имеют другую структуру, и если попробовать вызвать функцию `locals()` внутри класса -
будет виден лишь атрибут self.

Оптимальное решение проблемы - создать словарь, содержащий в себе в ключе название функции, а в значении ссылку на метод класса.

```
class YandexDiskOperations():
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_auth()
        self.dict_func = {'copy': self.copy, 'download': self.download}

    def additional_func(self):
        # print(locals())
        # locals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
        self.dict_func[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```